# Empty default sqlite in a Firefox 4 compatible extension

Tags: sqlite, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

I would like to provide a mechanism for a Firefox4-compatible extension I'm writing, to allow a local DB (developed by me in sqlite) to be originally created/copied to the profile folder.
In FF3.6 it was easy putting the empty sqlite db in the extension's default folder and copying it by code, but now the content of the extension seems unaccessible (extension is not unpacked, but xpi is directly stored) and I have to find a better way.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Livio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it by creating a [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files) from a chrome: or resource: URL that points to your default file in your extension.